# "Sold" equivalent for something free?

Tags: single-word-requests

Specifically, how could I say 20 tickets have been "sold" when I am referring to free tickets?

I've considered given out or given away, but **neither implies a person asking for a ticket** and being given one.

Comment: Probably *distributed* would do - or look at it from the other side of the transaction, and say they were *taken up*.

Comment: If you want to focus on the fact that people requested the tickets, you might reword your sentence to say that "We fulfilled requests for 20 tickets."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like FumbleFingers' "distributed" but ***"issued"*** would also work if you are referring to the tickets that have been requested.

Answer (score 2):

I might say,  “How many tickets have been *[comped](http://thesaurus.com/browse/free+seat)*?”  (*Comp* is a commonly-used abbreviated form of *[complimentary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complimentary)*.)  *[Cheapies](http://www.valleyadvocate.com/article.cfm?aid=15326)* and *freebies* are nouns used for such tickets, but I don't know of verb forms using those words. Note, the phrase *[bums on seats](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bums+on+seats)* in the valleyadvocate link above refers to fannies in seats, not hobos.